# How do I submit a Stack Exchange API query that returns the same results as the basic Stack Overflow search?

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

I am currently working on a project with the goal of determining the popularity of various topics on gis.stackexchange. I am using Python to interface with the stack exchange API. My issue is I am having trouble configuring the API query to match what a basic search using the search bar would return (showing posts containing the term (x)). I am currently using the /search/advanced... q="term" method, however I am getting empty results for search terms that might have around 100-200 posts. I have read a lot of the API documentation, but can't seem to configure the API query to match what a site search would yield.

Edit: For example, if I search, "Bayesian", I get 42 results on gis.stackexchange, but when I set q=Bayesian in the API request I get an empty return.

I have included my program below if it helps. Thanks!

```
#Interfacing_with_SO_API
import requests as rq
import json
import time

keywordinput = input('Enter your search term. If two words seperate by - : ')


baseurl = ('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/advanced?page=')

endurl = ('&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&q=' + keywordinput + '&site=gis.stackexchange&filter=!-nt6H9O0imT9xRAnV1gwrp1ZOq7FBaU7CRaGpVkODaQgDIfSY8tJXb')



urltot = ('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/advanced?page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&q=' + keywordinput + '&site=gis.stackexchange&filter=!-nt6H9O0imT9xRAnV1gwrp1ZOq7FBaU7CRaGpVkODaQgDIfSY8tJXb')
response = rq.get(urltot)

page = range(1,400)

if response.status_code == 400:
    print('Initial Response Code 400: Stopping')
    exit()
elif response.status_code == 200:
    print('Initial Response Code 200: Continuing')

datarr = []
for n in page:
    response = rq.get(baseurl + str(n) + endurl)
    print(baseurl + str(n) + endurl)
    time.sleep(2)
    if response.status_code == 400 or response.json()['has_more'] == False or n >400:
        print('No more pages')
        break
    elif response.json()['has_more'] == True:
        for data in response.json()['items']:
            if data['view_count'] >= 0:
                datarr.append(data)
                print(data['view_count'])
                print(data['answer_count'])
                print(data['score'])

#convert datarr to csv and save to file
with open(input('Search Term Name (filename): ') + '.csv', 'w') as f:
    for data in datarr:
        f.write(str(data['view_count']) + ',' + str(data['answer_count']) + ','+ str(data['score']) + '\n')
exit()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a query keyword that doesn't return what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the results for searching `bayesian` on the GIS StackExchange site, you'll get 42 results because the StackExchange site search returns both questions and answers that contain the term.

However, the standard [`/search` and `/search/advanced` API endpoints only search questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search), per the doc (emphasis mine):

> Searches a site for **any questions** which fit the given criteria
>
> Discussion
>
> Searches a site for any questions which fit the given criteria.

Instead, what you want to use is the [`/search/excerpts`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) endpoint, which will return both questions and answers.

Quick demo in the shell to show that it returns the same number of items:

```
curl -s --compressed "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/excerpts?page=1&pagesize=100&site=gis&q=bayesian" | jq '.["items"] | length'

42
```

And a minimal Python program to do the same:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# file: test_so_search.py

import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/excerpts"

    search_term = "bayesian"
    qs = {
        "page": 1,
        "pagesize": 100,
        "order": "desc",
        "sort": "votes",
        "site": "gis",
        "q": search_term
    }

    rsp = requests.get(api_url, qs)

    data = rsp.json()

    print(f"Got {len(data['items'])} results for '{search_term}'")
```

And output:

```
> python test_so_search.py
Got 42 results for 'bayesian'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately it seems the view_count item is not returned by the items in /search/excerpts. I need that item so I'm not sure how I will work around that.

Comment: @JayRad If you want the question view counts, you could pull in all the excerpts, and then use the [Questions API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids) and pass in question IDs (up to 100 at a time) to get fully populated question data. You can differentiate questions from answers as answers have `answer_id` fields but questions don't.